# Adjust Single Value within Tensor -- TensorFlow

Tags: indexing, addition, tensorflow

I feel embarrassed asking this, but how do you adjust a single value within a tensor? Suppose you want to add '1' to only one value within your tensor?

Doing it by indexing doesn't work:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

One approach would be to build an identically shaped tensor of 0's. And then adjusting a 1 at the position you want. Then you would add the two tensors together. Again this runs into the same problem as before.

I've read through the API docs several times and can't seem to figure out how to do this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**UPDATE:** TensorFlow 1.0 includes a [`tf.scatter_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) operator, which can be used to create `delta` below without creating a `tf.SparseTensor`.

---

This is actually surprisingly tricky with the existing ops! Perhaps somebody can suggest a nicer way to wrap up the following, but here's one way to do it.

Let's say you have a `tf.constant()` tensor:

```
c = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
```

...and you want to add `1.0` at location [1, 1]. One way you could do this is to define a [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#SparseTensor), `delta`, representing the change:

```
indices = [[1, 1]]  # A list of coordinates to update.

values = [1.0]  # A list of values corresponding to the respective
                # coordinate in indices.

shape = [3, 3]  # The shape of the corresponding dense tensor, same as `c`.

delta = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, shape)
```

Then you can use the [`tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_tensor_to_dense) op to make a dense tensor from `delta` and add it to `c`:

```
result = c + tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(delta)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(result)
# ==> array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
#            [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#            [ 0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you immensely. I agree with you that a function that can do this internally with more efficiency would be useful!

Comment: do you know how that handles values with the same index?

Comment: nvm it does not handle that well at all...

Do you know how to do this in the case of multiple indexes of the same value?

Comment: @dtracers: I believe those two other questions are relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157723/how-to-do-slice-assignment-in-tensorflow and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045797/conditional-assignment-of-tensor-values-in-tensorflow

Comment: Could you rewrite this using the `scatter_nd` operation ? Would it be more efficient to use a variable for c in the first place ?

Comment: @mrry why do you need `c`? won't `tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(delta)` already have 1 at `[1,1]` and 0 everywhere else?

Answer (score 8):

How about `tf.scatter_update(ref, indices, updates)` or `tf.scatter_add(ref, indices, updates)`?

```
ref[indices[...], :] = updates
ref[indices[...], :] += updates
```

See [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/sparse_variable_updates#scatter_update).

Comment: it's only valid if the `ref` is a Variable.

Comment: That restriction is actually more fundamental than it looks, if you see TF as a restricted (in terms of available recursion schemes), scalable runtime of a mostly-pure lazy functional language. Then you can see that the difficulty of efficiently updating a (pure) tensor is essentially the same as the one  you encounter in updating a purely functional data structure. Without that level of purity things wouldn't scale easily.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like the fact that `tf.assign`, `tf.scatter_nd`, `tf.scatter_update` functions only work on `tf.Variables` is not stressed enough. So there it is.

And in later versions of TensorFlow (tested with 1.14), you can use indexing on a `tf.Variable` to assign values to specific indices (again this only works on `tf.Variable` objects).

```
v = tf.Variable(tf.constant([[1,1],[2,3]]))
change_v = v[0,0].assign(4)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  print(sess.run(change_v))
```

Answer (score 1):

`tf.scatter_update` has no gradient descent operator assigned and will generate an error while learning with at least `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`. You have to implement bit manipulation with low level functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace certain indices, I would create a boolean tensor mask and a broadcasted tensor with the new values at the correct positions. Then use

```
new_tensor = tf.where(boolen_tensor_mask, new_values_tensor, old_values_tensor)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add 1 to element [2,0] (for example) of your tensor v (make sure your tensor is Variable), simply write:

```
v[2,0].assign(v[2,0]+1)
```