# Conditional assignment of tensor values in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to replicate the following `numpy` code in `tensorflow`. For example, I want to assign a `0` to all tensor indices that previously had a value of `1`.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1])
a[a==1] = 0

# a should be [0, 2, 3, 0]
```

If I write similar code in `tensorflow` I get the following error.

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

The condition in the square brackets should be arbitrary as in `a[a<1] = 0`.

Is there a way to realize this "conditional assignment" (for lack of a better name) in `tensorflow`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Comparison operators such as [greater than](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/greater) are available within TensorFlow API.

However, there is nothing equivalent to the concise NumPy syntax when it comes to manipulating the tensors directly. You have to make use of individual `comparison`, `where` and `assign` operators to perform the same action.

Equivalent code to your NumPy example is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable( [1,2,3,1] )    
start_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()    
comparison = tf.equal( a, tf.constant( 1 ) )    
conditional_assignment_op = a.assign( tf.where (comparison, tf.zeros_like(a), a) )

with tf.Session() as session:
    # Equivalent to: a = np.array( [1, 2, 3, 1] )
    session.run( start_op )
    print( a.eval() )    
    # Equivalent to: a[a==1] = 0
    session.run( conditional_assignment_op )
    print( a.eval() )

# Output is:
# [1 2 3 1]
# [0 2 3 0]
```

The print statements are of course optional, they are just there to demonstrate the code is performing correctly.

Comment: I believe with more recent release, this can be done with slice semantics: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/array_ops#Slicing_and_Joining

Comment: link to "Several comparison operators" in the answer is down. @Robert Lugg 's link is also down :/

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna I updated the link. I could not find a category section, so linked to an example.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also just starting to use tensorflow
Maybe some one will fill my approach more intuitive

```
import tensorflow as tf

conditionVal = 1
init_a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 1], dtype=tf.int32, name='init_a')
a = tf.Variable(init_a, dtype=tf.int32, name='a')
target = tf.fill(a.get_shape(), conditionVal, name='target')

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
condition = tf.not_equal(a, target)
defaultValues = tf.zeros(a.get_shape(), dtype=a.dtype)
calculate = tf.select(condition, a, defaultValues)

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init)
    session.run(calculate)
    print(calculate.eval())
```

main trouble is that it is difficult to implement "custom logic". if you could not explain your logic within linear math terms you need to write "custom op" library for tensorflow ([more details here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html))

Comment: Technically this does not update `a` i.e. you are missing the assignment step requested by the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1])
tf.where(tf.equal(a, 1), 0, a)
```

returns

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int32)>
```