# How to do slice assignment in Tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I found that Tensorflow provides `scatter_update()` to assign values to the slice of a tensor in the 0 dimension. For example, if the tensor `T` is three dimensional, I can assign value `v[1, :, :]` to `T[i, :, :]`.

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,36,36]))   
value = np.ones([1,36,36])   
d = tf.scatter_update(a,[0],value)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print a.eval()
    sess.run(d)
    print a.eval()
```

But how to assign values `v[1,1,:]` to `T[i,j,:]`?

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,36,36]))   
value1 = np.random.randn(1,1,36)    
e = tf.scatter_update(a,[0],value1) #Error

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print a.eval()
    sess.rum(e)
    print a.eval()
```

Is there any other function that TF provide or a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe what you need is the `assign_slice_update` discussed in [ticket #206](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206). <s>It is not yet available, though.</s>

**UPDATE: This is now implemented. See jdehesa's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139565/6531137**

---

Until `assign_slice_update` (or `scatter_nd()`) is available, you could build a block of the desired row containing the values you don't want to modify along with the desired values to update, like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10,36,36]))

i = 3
j = 5

# Gather values inside the a[i,...] block that are not on column j
idx_before = tf.concat(1, [tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.Variable([i]), [j]), [-1, 1]), tf.reshape(tf.range(j), [-1, 1])])
values_before = tf.gather_nd(a, idx_before)
idx_after = tf.concat(1, [tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.Variable([i]), [36-j-1]), [-1, 1]), tf.reshape(tf.range(j+1, 36), [-1, 1])])
values_after = tf.gather_nd(a, idx_after)

# Build a subset of tensor `a` with the values that should not be touched and the values to update
block = tf.concat(0, [values_before, 5*tf.ones([1, 36]), values_after])

d = tf.scatter_update(a, i, block)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    sess.run(d)
    print(a.eval()[3,4:7,:]) # Print a subset of the tensor to verify
```

The example generate a tensor of ones and performs `a[i,j,:] = 5`. Most of the complexity lies into getting the values that we don't want to modify, `a[i,~j,:]` (otherwise `scatter_update()` will replace those values).

If you want to perform `T[i,k,:] = a[1,1,:]` as you asked, you need to replace `5*tf.ones([1, 36])` in the previous example by `tf.gather_nd(a, [[1, 1]])`.

Another approach would be to create a mask to `tf.select()` the desired elements from it and assign it back to the variable, as such:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,36,36]))

i = tf.Variable([3])
j = tf.Variable([5])

# Build a mask using indices to perform [i,j,:]
atleast_2d = lambda x: tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1])
indices = tf.concat(1, [atleast_2d(tf.tile(i, [36])), atleast_2d(tf.tile(j, [36])), atleast_2d(tf.range(36))])
mask = tf.cast(tf.sparse_to_dense(indices, [10, 36, 36], 1), tf.bool)

to_update = 5*tf.ones_like(a)
out = a.assign( tf.select(mask, to_update, a) ) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    sess.run(out)
    print(a.eval()[2:5,5,:])
```

It is potentially less efficient in terms of memory since it requires twice the memory to handle the `a`-like `to_update` variable, but you could easily modify this last example to get a gradient-preserving operation from the `tf.select(...)` node. You might also be interested in looking at this other StackOverflow question: [Conditional assignment of tensor values in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045797/conditional-assignment-of-tensor-values-in-tensorflow).

Those inelegant contortions should be replaced to a call to the proper TensorFlow function as it becomes available.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example! As you said, the current way is somewhat inelegant. I hope `assign_slice_update` function available soon.

Comment: tf.select has been replaced with tf.where in tensorflow 1.

Comment: Is there a way to perform T[:,k,:] = a[:,1,:] where a may not necessarly be a variable.

Answer (score 52):

Currently, you can do slice assignment for variables in TensorFlow. There is no specific named function for it, but you can select a slice and call `assign` on it:

```
my_var = my_var[4:8].assign(tf.zeros(4))
```

First, note that (after having looked at [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#__getitem__)) it seems that the return value of [`assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign), even when applied to a slice, is always a reference to the *whole* variable after applying the update.

EDIT: The information below is either deprecated, imprecise or was always wrong. The fact is that the returned value of `assign` is a tensor that can be readily used and already incorporates the dependency to the assignment, so simply evaluating that or using it in further operations will ensure it gets executed without need for an explicit `tf.control_dependencies` block.

---

Note, also, that this will only add the assignment op to the graph, but will not run it unless it is explicitly executed or set as a dependency of some other operation. A good practice is to use it in a `tf.control_dependencies` context:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([my_var[4:8].assign(tf.zeros(4))]):
    my_var = tf.identity(my_var)
```

You can read more about it in TensorFlow issue [#4638](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4638).

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I am currently trying to use this and am getting an error that gradients are not defined for this operation. (LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'strided_slice/_assign' (op type: StridedSliceAssign).
Do you happen to know of any workarounds for that? Or the analogous "scatter_*" operation that would have gradients defined?

Comment: @WayneTreible Assign operations do not have gradients, indeed. If what you want is to replace some particular values in a tensor for some computation you have to manually construct the whole tensor. Here are a couple of examples: [using concatenations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534185/1782792) and [using a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49493702/1782792). If these don't work for you maybe you can post a full question with more details about your case and some code (feel free to link it here later).

Comment: Hey, jdehesa. I posted my question with some more info over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755316/best-way-to-mimic-pytorch-sliced-assignment-with-keras-tensorflow

Thanks for the advice, I'll continue to work on a solution in the meantime.

Comment: Note that this can be very inefficient, esp in `tf.function` or eager-mode, as the slice access will also cause a read (potential copy) of the full variable, and then the slice op (also unnecessary), and only then `ResourceStridedSliceAssign`. You can instead also call `tf.raw_ops.ResourceStridedSliceAssign` directly, which avoids all of that. (In graph mode, it would not be so relevant, as those unused ops would not be computed.)

Comment: @Albert Good point, the answer was first written for TF 1.x, before eager mode was around. Although I imagine the case of `tf.function` would be the same as graph mode?

Comment: I tried that code with `tf.function` with `autograph=True` and it was a big difference after these changes. I assume because it would add the control dependencies. Although my comparison was not direct, I also had `my_var[4:8]` read access in different parts of my code, which I changed to `tf.raw_ops.ResourceGather`.

Comment: @Albert That's interesting to know, thanks for trying it out and the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The `tf.scatter_update` can modify the tensor in the first dimension. As stated in the documentation,

> indices: A Tensor. Must be one of the following types: int32, int64. A tensor of indices into the first dimension of ref.

You can use `scatter_nd_update` function to do what you want. As shown below, which I have tested.

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,36,36])) 
value1 = np.random.randn(1,36)
e = tf.scatter_nd_update(a,[[0,1]],value1)
init= tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
print(a.eval())
sess.run(e)
```

Comment: This answer isn't incorrect, but there is an important caviat: as Tensors are not Variables (I know the OP was using variables), when someone tries to use this method to update a Tensor, it is susceptible to the error:
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_lazy_read'

Answer (score 1):

**Answer for TF2:**

Unfortunately, there is still no elegant way to do this in Tensorflow 2 (TF2).

The best way I found was to unstack assign and then restack:

```
x = tf.random.uniform(shape=(5,))
new_val = 7
y = tf.unstack(x)
y[2] = new_val
x_updated = tf.stack(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update`.  Here is an example for the specific case of assigning a particular value to a slice from a 2d array.

```
def tf_assign_slice_2d(heatmap: TensorHeatmap, left: int, top: int, right: int, bottom: int, value: float):
    bw = right - left
    bh = bottom - top
    ixs = tf.range(bw * bh)
    i_ixs = ixs // bw + top
    j_ixs = ixs % bw + left
    ij_ixs = tf.stack([i_ixs, j_ixs], axis=1)
    return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(heatmap, ij_ixs, value+tf.zeros(bh*bw, dtype=heatmap.dtype))
```

Passes test:

```
def test_assign_slice_2d():
    mat = tf.constant([
        [2, 5, 1, 6],
        [8, 4, 2, 4],
        [7, 2, 0, 2],
    ])
    result = tf_assign_slice_2d(mat, 1, 0, 3, 2, value=-1)
    assert np.array_equal(result.numpy(),[
        [2, -1, -1, 6],
        [8, -1, -1, 4],
        [7, 2, 0, 2],
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the function `tf.raw_ops.ResourceStridedSliceAssign` you can use, like:

```py
tf.raw_ops.ResourceStridedSliceAssign(
    ref=my_var.handle,
    begin=[4],
    end=[8],
    strides=[1],
    value=tf.zeros(4),
)
```