# How to assign a value to a tf.Variable in TensorFlow without using tf.assign

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a variable that contains the 4x4 identitiy matrix. 
I wish to assign some values to this matrix (these values are learned by the model).

When I use `tf.assign()` I get an error saying that strided slices do not have gradients. 
My question is how can I do this without using `tf.assign()`

Here is a sample code of the desired behaviour(without the error, since the values are not learned here) :

```
params = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
M = tf.Variable(tf.eye(4, batch_shape=[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
M = tf.assign(M[:, 0:3, 3], params)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
output_val = sess.run(M)
```

Note - the variable is created solely for the purpose of housing these parameters.

UPDATE:  I am adding a minimal working example that creates the error. (obviously training like this won't result in anything good. Its just to illustrate the error since my code is far too long to copy here)

```
params = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
M_gt = np.eye(4)
M_gt[0:3, 3] = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

M = tf.Variable(tf.eye(4, batch_shape=[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
M = tf.assign(M[:, 0:3, 3], params)

loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(M - M_gt)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
sess.run(train_op)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do slice assignment in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157723/how-to-do-slice-assignment-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @jdehesa, thanks. the question is similar but I didnt fully understand the answer. What does `with tf.control_dependencies([my_var[4:8].assign(tf.zeros(4))]):
    my_var = tf.identity(my_var)` do? I have multiple assignment lines in my final code, do I need to copy htis multiple times?

Comment: Actually, looking at [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#__getitem__) again, I think it's fine if you just do `my_var = my_var[4:8].assign(tf.zeros(4))`; the return value of [`assign`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign), even if it's applied to a slice, returns the value of the *whole* variable after the assignment has taken place (I'll fix/add a comment in the other answer)...

Comment: @jdehesa ok but this still doesn't solve my problem.  After using your suggested way of assignment I still get the error `No gradient defined for operation strided slice...` (I also had to define each assignment as a variable again for some reason)

Comment: Mmm, maybe you could show a minimal example where you get the error, to have a better idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @jdehesa I added a minimal example that creates the error.

Comment: Ahh I see, so you want to replace a block in `M` with some values and use that later, right? And do you wally want to replace the stored value in `M`. Or, do you really need a variable at all, or just something that gets that block replaced?

Comment: @jdehesa I want to replace the values in M with some parameters that are learned by a DNN. This M will take part in the loss function (similar to the example) so the gradients should update these parameters. I am currently trying a workaround with some `tf.concat` (similar to the answer in the post you referenced) but I thought there might be a better solution.

Comment: Right, I understand. Afaik, I think that you need to build the matrix by hand, like you suggest. I posted a possible answer, not sure if it's the best way but I think it works for your case (at least for the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you could do what (I think) you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    params = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
    M_gt = np.eye(4)
    M_gt[0:3, 3] = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

    M = tf.Variable(tf.eye(4, batch_shape=[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
    params_t = tf.constant(params, dtype=tf.float32)

    shape_m = tf.shape(M)
    batch_size = shape_m[0]
    num_m = shape_m[1]
    num_params = tf.shape(params_t)[1]

    last_column = tf.concat([tf.tile(tf.transpose(params_t)[tf.newaxis], (batch_size, 1, 1)),
                             tf.zeros((batch_size, num_m - num_params, 1), dtype=params_t.dtype)], axis=1)
    replace = tf.concat([tf.zeros((batch_size, num_m, num_m - 1), dtype=params_t.dtype), last_column], axis=2)

    r = tf.range(num_m)
    ii = r[tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis]
    jj = r[tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :]
    mask = tf.tile((ii < num_params) & (tf.equal(jj, num_m - 1)), (batch_size, 1, 1))
    M_replaced = tf.where(mask, replace, M)

    loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(M_replaced - M_gt[np.newaxis])
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    M_val, M_replaced_val = sess.run([M, M_replaced])
    print('M:')
    print(M_val)
    print('M_replaced:')
    print(M_replaced_val)
```

Output:

```
M:
[[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]]
M_replaced:
[[[ 1.  0.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  1.  0.  2.]
  [ 0.  0.  1.  3.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.]]]
```