# Best way to mimic PyTorch sliced assignment with Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to mimic the operation done in PyTorch below:

```
vol = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(A, B*2, C, D, E).zero_()).cuda()
for i in range(C):
  if i > 0 :
    vol[:, :B, i, :,i:] = input0[:,:,:,i:]
    vol[:, B:, i, :,i:] = input1[:,:,:,:-i]
  else:
    vol[:, :B, i, :,:] = input0
    vol[:, B:, i, :,:] = input1
```

So far, I have tried using the following sliced assignment in TF and wrapping it in a Keras Lambda layer:

```
vol = tf.Variable(K.zeros((A, D, E, C, B*2)))
for i in range(C):
  if i > 0:
    vol[:, :, i:, i, :B].assign(input0[:,:,i:,:])
    vol[:, :, i:, i, B:].assign(input1[:,:,:-i,:])
  else:
    vol[:, :, :, i, :B].assign(input0)
    vol[:, :, :, i, B:].assign(input1)
return vol
```

I also tried `vol = vol[...].assign(...)`.

This assigns the values to the `vol` variable correctly, which I can then convert to a tensor to use in the rest of my graph. However, the gradient of this operation is undefined in TF (`LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'strided_slice/_assign' (op type: StridedSliceAssign)`), and the gradient doesn't get propagated to the previous layers that generate `input0` and `input1`, while they do appear to get transferred in the PyTorch implementation. Is there a way to construct this same variable in TF such that the gradient is defined and my previous operations don't have a `None` gradient?

Comment: Do you really need to save the value in a variable (to use it in later calls to `run`), or you just need the tensor with the modified values for a later computation in the graph, but within the same call to `run`?

Comment: I just need the tensor, the Variable was the only way I was able to get the assignment to work. This is effectively a concatenate operation of two previous network branches into a volume which then is operated on by a 3D Conv net. In order to go end-to-end I need the gradients to exist for this operation. I don't really need to use it in later runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct the tensor "by hand". Assuming both `input0` and `input1` have shape (`A`, `D`, `E`, `B`), you can do something like this:

```
# Make the indexing mask with TensorFlow
in_shape = tf.shape(input0)
in_dims = 4
idx = tf.meshgrid(*[tf.range(in_shape[i]) for i in range(in_dims)], indexing='ij')[2]
idx = tf.expand_dims(idx, axis=3)
r = tf.range(C)[tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis]
mask = idx >= r

# If all dimensions are known at graph construction time, you can instead
# make the mask with NumPy like this to save graph computation time
idx = np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(d) for d in (A, D, E, B)], indexing='ij')[2]
idx = np.expand_dims(idx, 3)
r = np.arange(C)[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
mask = idx >= r

# Make the tensor
input0_tile = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(input0, 3), (1, 1, 1, C, 1))
input1_tile = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(input1, 3), (1, 1, 1, C, 1))
zero_tile = tf.zeros_like(input0_tile)
vol0 = np.where(mask, input0_tile, zero_tile)
vol1 = np.where(mask, input1_tile, zero_tile)
vol = tf.concat([vol0, vol1], axis=-1)
```

Note that you need either the first or the second block followed by the third block, not the three blocks (see comments). The code builds a binary mask using a [`tf.meshgrid`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/meshgrid) and a [`tf.range`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/range) of indices, then uses [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) to select values from the inputs or zeros.

Answer (score 3):

A tf.Variable is sort of a primitive/basic type. You shouldn't want to gradients to propagate out of them.

What you want is to construct a node that outputs the 5 dimensional tensor like you want.

I would run a concatenate operation on the 4th dimension to build the tensor and use the result in place of the `vol`.

If you don't care about the gradients propagating to input0 and input1, then I would just build the tensor outside of tensorflow and use it as an initializer.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying this originally because this is *high level* the best solution. The issue I was having was the masking portion shown by jdehesa