# How to assign an image to an image patch

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to implement a cut-out strategy as a data augmentation method. For this strategy, a random rectangular region of an image is selected and replaced by random noise. However, I could not figure out how to "assign" a random image (with shape HxWxD) to a rectangular region of a larger image. A MATLAB code to what I need would be something like:

```
large_image(patch_start_y:patch_end_y, patch_start_x:patch_end_x, :) = random_noise_image
```

Following is my efforts to achieve an equivalent result. This is how I get a random image:

```
random_patch = tf.random_uniform([cut_out_height, cut_out_width, tf.constant(3)], minval=tf.constant(0),
                                 maxval=tf.constant(256), dtype=tf.int32)

random_patch = tf.expand_dims(random_patch, 0)
```

And this is how I tried to assign it to an existing image, having a shape of (1, ?, ?, 3)

```
return tf.assign(image[0, cut_out_start_y:(cut_out_start_y+cut_out_height),
          cut_out_start_x:(cut_out_start_x+cut_out_width), :], random_patch, validate_shape=False)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
    From merging shape 2 with other shapes. for 'strided_slice/stack_2' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [], [1], [1], [].
```

Any ideas?

**Update**: I have come to the conclusion that the problem is the image and the patch being a tf.Tensor. For tf.Variable type, tf.assign works just fine. See below MWE for the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
image = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8], [9, 10, 11,12], [13,14,15,16]]
patch = [[9, 8],[7,6]]
image_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(image)
patch_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(patch)
modified_image = tf.assign(image_tensor[1:3, 1:3], patch_tensor)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(modified_image))
```

It gives:

```
ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
```

Is there a workaround to achieve what I want?

Comment: So image is a numpy array?

Comment: If first dimension in shape is 1, the first index should be 0, not 1.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, you are right. However, I have changed it and I still get the same error. Image is a tf.Tensor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need an explicit `tf.constant`, even if the conversion will happen under the hood anyway.

Comment: Does this post work? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39157723/2988730

Comment: In particular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139565/2988730

Comment: `return image[0, cut_out_start_y:cut_out_start_y+cut_out_height, 
          cut_out_start_x:cut_out_start_x+cut_out_width, :].assign(random_patch)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist No, still gives the same error

Comment: Sorry, one more step: `random_patch = tf.random_uniform([tf.constant(1), cut_out_height, cut_out_width, tf.constant(3)], minval=tf.constant(0),
                                 maxval=tf.constant(256), dtype=tf.int32)` gotta make those shapes match

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I did not include in the code sample above but they are already of the same size. I ensured that by using tf.expand_dims on patch. But for clarity I will add this to code also.