# Tensorflow: Operations With Block-diagonal Matrices

Tags: performance, tensorflow, memory-efficient

I'm looking for a way to implement block-diagonal matrices in Tensorflow. Specifically, I have block-diagonal matrix A with N blocks of size S x S each. Further, I have a vector v of length N*S. I want to calculate A dot v. Is there any efficient way to do it in Tensorflow?

Also, I would prefer the implementation which supports a batch dimension of v (e.g. its real dimension is batch_size x (N*S)) and which is memory efficient, keeping in memory only block-diagonal parts of A.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert your tensor to a [sparse tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor) since a block-diagonal matrix is just a special case of it. Then, the operations are done in a efficient way. If you already have a dense representation of the tensor you can just cast it using [`sparse_tensor = tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse(dense_tensor)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/dense_to_sparse). Otherwise, you can construct it with the `tf.SparseTensor(...)` function. To get the indices, you might use [`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice), see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107678/update-slice-of-tensor-in-tensorflow) for more information.