# How to do sliced assign at Keras(using TensorFlow as backend)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For example,

```
a = Input(...)
b = keras.layers.Conv2D(...)(a)
c = keras.backend.zeros(...)

c[...].assign(b[...])
```

Because it's used before a model is compiled, when I try to use the function `assign()` (this is a TensorFlow function), there comes the error:
'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'.

This is probably because before the model is compiled, the first dim of the variable is `None`.
So, is there any way to do a sliced assign ?

Comment: It's too little context in your question. And compiled model likely has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

In general, TensorFlow tensors are not assignable. However, as per official [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign),  `tf.assign()` function works only with mutable Tensors, which should be from a Variable node. So, the code below works. The rest will depend heavily on your particular case.

```py
var1 = tf.keras.backend.zeros(1,1)
var2 = var1[0].assign(1)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(var2))
```

You may find this answer useful
[How to do slice assignment in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157723/how-to-do-slice-assignment-in-tensorflow/43139565#43139565)