# How do I update part of a variable/placeholder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here's part of the code I am using:

```
noise = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((299, 299, 3)))
sess.run(noise.initializer)
op1 = tf.assign(subX,x_hat-x)
op3 = tf.assign(noise[125:175, 125:175], subX)
op2 = tf.assign(x_hat,noise+x)
```

As you can see, for op3, I am trying to assign part of the Variable "noise" from subX, which is determined by. However, I am getting this error:

> UnimplementedError: 2 root error(s) found.   (0) Unimplemented: sliced
>   l-value shape [50,50,3] does not match r-value shape [299,299,3].
>   Automatic broadcasting not yet implemented.    [[node
>   strided_slice_2/_assign (defined at
>   :10) ]]     [[Assign_15/_821]]   (1)
>   Unimplemented: sliced l-value shape [50,50,3] does not match r-value
>   shape [299,299,3]. Automatic broadcasting not yet implemented.
>   [[node strided_slice_2/_assign (defined at
>   :10) ]] 0 successful operations. 0
>   derived errors ignored.
>
> Errors may have originated from an input operation. Input Source
>   operations connected to node strided_slice_2/_assign:  Variable/read
>   (defined at :7)   Variable_5 (defined at
>   :7)
>
> Input Source operations connected to node strided_slice_2/_assign: 
>   Variable/read (defined at :7)
>   Variable_5 (defined at :7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do slice assignment in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157723/how-to-do-slice-assignment-in-tensorflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple mistake on this line:

`op3 = tf.assign(noise[125:175, 125:175], subX)`

subX is a different size from noise; a bit hard to infer since I didn't add it within the details.