# Tensorflow iterating through tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im using Tensorflow 1.13. However I get an error saying that I can't iterate through a tensor unless I'm in eager mode. Is there a way of doing this without going into eager mode?

```
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    context = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, None])
    mask = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, 2])
    output = model.model(hparams=hparams, X=context)



    for batch_index in range(args.batch_size):
        start = mask[batch_index][0]
        end   = mask[batch_index][1]

        for i in range(start, end+1):
            output['logits'][batch_index, i , context[batch_index,i]].assign(math.inf)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=context[:, 1:],  logits=output['logits'][:, :-1]))
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: Hi @gorjan this is quite difficult to do. Could you see the comments in Achintha's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop)? You could try the following snippet (possibly with minor modifications for your code) and see whether it works?

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.9)
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
    context = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, None])
    mask = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, 2])
    output = model.model(hparams=hparams, X=context)



    for batch_index in [0,1,2,3]: #I have assumed a dummy list cz we can't iterate through a 'Dimension'
        start = mask[batch_index][0]
        end   = mask[batch_index][1]

        i = tf.constant(0)
        while_condition = lambda i: (tf.less(i, end)) & (tf.math.greater_equal(i,start))

        def body(i):
            return output['logits'][batch, i , context[batch,i]].assign(math.inf)

        r = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, [i])

        # for i in range(start, end+1):
        #     output['logits'][batch, i , context[batch,i]].assign(math.inf)

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=context[:, 1:],  logits=output['logits'][:, :-1]))
```

Comment: When I run `sess.run(loss, feed_dict={...})` how do I ensure that the `while_loop` is being executed?

Comment: I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Can you try some sample inputs and run the session with `loss_r, r_r = sess.run([loss,r], feed_dict={...})`? And see whether you get the expected training performance?

Comment: This is a different error happens in the line `labels=context[:, 1:],  logits=output['logits'][:, :-1]))` right? Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157723/how-to-do-slice-assignment-in-tensorflow.

Comment: It turns out the error comes from the `assign` part. See here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py#L978

Comment: I found someone else with a similar problem here : https://www.manongdao.com/q-716462.html