# Tensorflow 2 - How to conditionally update values directly in tf.Variable

Tags: tensorflow

## Question

Please advise how to conditionally update the original tf.Variable. This is a different question from [conditional assignment of tf.variable in Tensorflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449671/conditional-assignment-of-tf-variable-in-tensorflow-2).

## Background

`tf.Variable` is mutable and the `assign` method would update the same memory area. It looks the `assign` method does not have an option to incorporate condition when assigning values. Hence I suppose [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) is to update tf.Variable conditionally.

- [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)

```
Returns:
    If x and y are provided: 
        A Tensor with the same type as x and y, and shape that is broadcast from the condition, x, and y.
    Otherwise: 
        A Tensor with shape (num_true, dim_size(condition)).
```

In numpy, indexing can be used to directly update the numpy array but there looks no such way in Tensorflow.

```
# Numpy conditional uddate with boolean indexing
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(3, 4))
x[x > 0] = 0
```

#### Problem

As `tf.Variable` is mutable, expected that the `tf.where` will mutate the original Variable, however as below, the original Variable `x` has not been updated.

```
x = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(3,4)), dtype=tf.float32)
print(f"x:{x}\n")
print(f"x > 0:\n{x > 0}\n")
print(f"tf.where(x>0, 1, x):\n{tf.where(x>0, 1, x)}")

x  # check if updated
```

Result:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Original tf.Variable x
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x is <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.8015974 ,  0.8223503 , -0.2704468 ,  0.01874248],
       [ 0.46989247,  0.4753061 , -0.06808566, -0.57646054],
       [ 0.07082719,  0.2924774 , -0.12741995,  0.3168819 ]],
      dtype=float32)>

x > 0 is [[ True  True False  True]
 [ True  True False False]
 [ True  True False  True]]

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Update using tf.where
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tf.where(x>0, 1, x)=
[[ 1.          1.         -0.2704468   1.        ]
 [ 1.          1.         -0.06808566 -0.57646054]
 [ 1.          1.         -0.12741995  1.        ]]

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The x is the same as before.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.8015974 ,  0.8223503 , -0.2704468 ,  0.01874248],
       [ 0.46989247,  0.4753061 , -0.06808566, -0.57646054],
       [ 0.07082719,  0.2924774 , -0.12741995,  0.3168819 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

Please help me understand if there is a way to directly update `x`.

---

## Notes

- [How to efficiently update a tensor slice? #36559](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36559)

> First, the return value from the slide op is a Tensor, which is not the original variable.
>
> ```
> var_slice = var[4:5]
> var_slice.assign(math_ops.sub(var, const))
> ```
>
> With a tensor, it doesn't have methods like "assign" or "assign_add" etc.
>
> I think the most feasible way to create a TensorArray, which contains
> your slides of mean/variance value, and read/write to it within the
> call() body for cell. Once the layer goes over all the timesteps, you
> can do a stack for the TensorArray and assign the value back to the
> variable itself. You don't have to continuously write to the variable
> when processing the timesteps, since timestep t shouldn't affect the
> result in t+1 (if I understand your problem correctly)

- [How to efficiently assign to a slice of a tensor in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092147/how-to-efficiently-assign-to-a-slice-of-a-tensor-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a `tf.Variable`, you need to call `assign`. Read more in the [Introduction to Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable) guide.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.random.set_seed(0)
>>> x = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform((3,4),-1,1), dtype=tf.float32)
>>> x
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.41604972, -0.5868671 ,  0.07078147,  0.12251496],
       [-0.16665101,  0.6156559 , -0.0135498 ,  0.9962585 ],
       [ 0.3934703 , -0.7492528 ,  0.4196334 ,  0.32483125]],
      dtype=float32)>
>>> x.assign(tf.where(x>0,x,0))
<tf.Variable 'UnreadVariable' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.07078147, 0.12251496],
       [0.        , 0.6156559 , 0.        , 0.9962585 ],
       [0.3934703 , 0.        , 0.4196334 , 0.32483125]], dtype=float32)>
>>> x
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.07078147, 0.12251496],
       [0.        , 0.6156559 , 0.        , 0.9962585 ],
       [0.3934703 , 0.        , 0.4196334 , 0.32483125]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more cases. The main takeaway is that to update the content in `tf.Variable`, we use `assign`. But note that it will assign the value eagerly.

```
x = tf.Variable(range(5), shape=(5,), name="a")
x.numpy()
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)

x.assign(tf.where(x > 2, x, -1)).numpy()
array([-1, -1, -1,  3,  4], dtype=int32)

x.assign(range(5,10)).numpy()
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)

x.assign(tf.where(x < 8, tf.range(5), tf.where(x > 8 , x, -1))).numpy()
array([ 0,  1,  2, -1,  9], dtype=int32)
```