# Clipping(Filtering) tf.placeholder values

Tags: tensorflow

I want to change my tf.placeholder values such that:

values < SmallConstant is set to 0.

It's not exactly clipping, so I can't use: `tf.clip_by_value()`

I tried the suggestion in [Conditional assignment of tensor values in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045797/conditional-assignment-of-tensor-values-in-tensorflow), and this is what I have so far:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None)
condition = tf.less(x, tf.constant(SmallConst))
tf.assign(x, tf.where(condition, tf.zeros_like(x), x))
```

However, on running this, I get an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

It seems `tf.assign()` can be done on `tf.Variable` but not on `tf.placeholder`.

Is there any other way I can do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's even easier than you think:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None)
# create a bool tensor the same shape as x
condition = x < SmallConst 

# create tensor same shape as x, with values greater than SmallConst set to 0
to_remove = x*tf.to_float(condition)

# set all values of x less than SmallConst to 0
x_clipped = x - to_remove
```

I'd normally just put that into one line like:

```
x_clipped = x - x*tf.to_float(x < small_const)
```

*note:* using `tf.to_float` on a tensor of type `bool` will give you `0.0`s in place of `False`s and `1.0`s in place of `True`s

---

Additional information for cleaner code:

The numerical operators (e.g. `<`, `>=`, `+`, `-` etc, but not `==`) are overloaded for tensorflow tensors such that you can use native python variables with tensors to get a new tensor that is the result of that operation. So `tf.constant()` is actually fairly rarely actually needed. Example of this in action:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
b = a + 1
c = a > 0
print(b) # gives "<tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=int32>"
print(c) # gives "<tf.Tensor 'Greater:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=bool>"
sess.run(b, {a: 1}) # gives scalar int32 numpy array with value 2
sess.run(c, {a: 1}) # gives scalar bool numpy array with value True
```

This is also true of numpy.

---

[`tf.assign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) only works on Variables because it will

> Update 'ref' by assigning 'value' to it.

Tensors in tensorflow are immutable. The result of any operation on a tensor is another tensor, but the original tensor will never change. Variables, however are mutable, and you change their value with `tf.assign()`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.