# tensorflow: how to assign values upon meeting a given condition

Tags: pandas, tensorflow

For example, in pandas DataFrame and Series, I can replace 0s with 0.00001 by doing this:

```
df[df['C']==0]['C'] = 0.00001
```

Now in TensorFlow, I have a n * 1 tensor, I also would like to replace all 0 values with 0.00001. How can I do this?

Comment: It may be a duplicate problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045797/conditional-assignment-of-tensor-values-in-tensorflow.

Comment: That's indeed a similar question. But is there any more updated approach to this?