# How do I update elements of a tensor using indices?

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow

I'm looking for an "update" function that takes in a tensor `t1`, some indices and values and returns a new tensor `t2`, which is `t1` but with the values at the indices changed accordingly.

This seems like the most basic of functions, but I do not see it in the documentation.

What I do see is [`tf.scatter_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update), which updates values in a `Variable`: in a way it is what I want.  I could conceivably construct a `Variable` for `t2` (would this work?), but `t2` is not supposed to be a stateful variable and I would be populating it with arbitrary initial values.

Or, I could manually construct a Python nested list adding each element of `t1` and `t2` individually, then calling [`tf.convert_to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor).  I could be wrong, but this seems likely to horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [tf.scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) or `tf.scatter_add` to update tensor value according to indices.

See the question [adjust-single-value-within-tensor-tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685947/adjust-single-value-within-tensor-tensorflow) for a reference.