# Tensorflow: How do change one element in tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to change one element in tensor

Example:

let there be a variable

```
v = tf.Variable([1, 2, 3])
```

how do I change the value of element with index 1 in tensor v?

I wish: v[1] = v[1] * 15

Comment: check this link , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685947/adjust-single-value-within-tensor-tensorflow

Comment: thank you. But this is strange method