# Modify a Tensorflow Variable inside a loop

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, while-loop

I would like to modify certain indexes of a Variable inside a while loop.
Basically convert the python code below to Tensorflow:

```
import numpy
tf_variable=numpy.zeros(10,numpy.int32)
for i in range (10):
    tf_variable[i]=i
tf_variable
```

Tensorflow code would look like following: except it gives error

```
import tensorflow as tf
var=tf.get_variable('var',initializer=tf.zeros([10],tf.int32),trainable=False)
itr=tf.constant(0)
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #initializing variables


print('itr=',sess.run(itr))
def w_c(itr,var):
    return(tf.less(itr,10))
def w_b(itr,var):
    var=tf.assign(var[1],9) #lets say i want to modify index 1 of variable var
    itr=tf.add(itr,1)
    return [itr,var] #these tensors when returning actually get called


OP=tf.while_loop(w_c,w_b,[itr,var],parallel_iterations=1,back_prop=False)
print(sess.run(OP))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its quite a unique thing to do I am sure if you express your problem in further detail, I can help you better but if you intend to change a variable in a tf.variable, this is what I will suggest

```
tf_Variable=tf.random_normal([1,10])
array=tf.Session().run(tf_Variable)
print(array)
```

> array([[ 1.8884579 , -1.4278126 , -1.5084593 ,  **2.2028043** ,  0.10910247,
>           -1.6836789 ,  0.41359457,  2.0960712 ,  0.5169063 , -0.66555417]],
>         dtype=float32)

```
array[0][3]=2
print(array)
```

> array([[ 1.8884579 , -1.4278126 , -1.5084593 ,  **2.**        ,  0.10910247,
>           -1.6836789 ,  0.41359457,  2.0960712 ,  0.5169063 , -0.66555417]],
>         dtype=float32)

you can again feed this into a tf variable if you like [As is explained here](https://www.aiworkbox.com/lessons/initialize-a-tensorflow-variable-with-numpy-values)

Comment: how to do it inside a tensorflow while_loop?

Comment: How will the loop look like do share that, I will be able to write the exact code

Comment: I have added tensorflow code to the question which generates error

Comment: The issue is that the built in while loop for tf converts the variable to `Tensor("while/Identity_1:0", shape=(10,), dtype=int32`

and that is precisely why you are not able to assign with slices as its only supported for a variable. 
I will suggest that either you change your code or build a custom while loop to perform these operations

Answer (score 0):

Making a "detour" over the CPU is not always feasible (you lose the gradients). Here is a possibility how to implement your numpy example in TensorFlow (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685947/adjust-single-value-within-tensor-tensorflow/34686952#34686952][1]) and an answer I gave on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615979/change-a-single-value-of-a-tensor-inside-a-while-loop/54616400#54616400))

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf_variable = tf.Variable(tf.ones([10]))

def body(i, v):
    index = i
    new_value = tf.to_float(i)
    delta_value = new_value - v[index:index+1]
    delta = tf.SparseTensor([[index]], delta_value, (10,))
    v_updated = v + tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(delta)
    return tf.add(i, 1), v_updated


_, updated = tf.while_loop(lambda i, _: tf.less(i, 10), body, [0, tf_variable])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(tf_variable))
    print(sess.run(updated))
```

This prints

```
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
```