# Tensorflow: how to change specific values in tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have the following code

```
aa = tf.zeros([10, 4, 240, 240, 1])
aa[:, :, 10:20, 5:15, :] = 1
```

However, this does not work.

I know that numpy arrays allow specific elements to be changed using the notation `aa[:, :, 10:20, 5:15, :] = 1`. How would I do this in tensorflow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adjust Single Value within Tensor -- TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685947/adjust-single-value-within-tensor-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.concat()`:

```
aa = tf.zeros([10, 4, 240, 240, 1])
aaa = tf.concat(
    (
        aa[..., :10, 5:15, :],
        tf.ones((10, 4, 10, 10, 1)),
        aa[..., 20:, 5:15, :],
    ),
    2
)
aa = tf.concat(
    (
        aa[..., :5, :],
        aaa,
        aa[..., 15:, :],
    ),
    3
)
```

Comment: Hi, so this actually doesn't do what I want it to. If a 240x240 image is plotted it will contain a cross of 1s instead of a rectangle of 1s. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for the late acceptance - I was swamped with unrelated work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with a simpler shape. I can see the changes but not sure if you are getting what you want here.

```
aa =  tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10, 4, 20, 20, 1]))

tensor = tf.constant(10,shape=(10,4,10,10,1))
tf.print(aa[:, :, 10:20, 5:15, :].assign(tf.ones_like(tensor, dtype=tf.float32)))

tf.print(aa[:, :, 10:20, 5:15, :],summarize=-1)
tf.print(aa,summarize=-1)
```